# import bs4 from BeautifulSoup on PyCharm Community version does not work

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I am totally new here and new to Python. I thought I could learn something new in my 40ties : )

I went through some online courses and I know basics... I though it would be easier to learn while doing something cool. I decided to write code to pick prices of Amazon.

I found few Youtube videos which explain how to do it and it seem to work at their end but at my end it is not so fun : (

YT Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyW6YK7ftis

I am using PyCharm Community version.

I have a problem with *import bs4 from BeautifulSoup*. PyCharm keeps telling me "Unresolved reference 'BeautifulSoup'" and offer to install it. When I try to do it I get an error, it failed.

I am sure I have installed it via CMD (Windows 10) and when I try its version I get it ok:

Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.0.1)

What am I doing wrong that PyCharm does not see it? How to fix it?

Thank you.

Edit: I installed Python 3.8 today.

Comment: create a file in pycharm, and put this content in it. `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; print("it has been imported")` what's the output of that?

Comment: It prints it has been imported

Comment: congrats, you have `bs4` working on your IDE, now go ahead and follow the tutorial if you want also please mark @Dratius answer as correct

Comment: Why does PyCharm generates the error: Unused import statement 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;' ?

Comment: That's a warning not an error, it's pretty much says "hey, you have imported this library but you haven't used it anywhere in your code. So maybe if you dont need it remove it so the loading time of your app can be a little better."

Comment: Thank you. I do appreciate. When I wrote few lines of code it disappeared.